# How I can be aware of a code change in the return when using unpacking

Tags: python

Recently I have a problem when a coworker made a change in a signature for a function return, we have clients that call the function in this way:

```
example = function()
```

But then as I was depending on his changes, he unintentionally change to this:

```
example, other_stuff = function()
```

I was not aware of this change, I did the merge and everything seem ok but then the error happen as I was expecting one value, but now it was trying to unpack two

So my question is knowing python is not a typed language, is there a way to know this happen and prevent this behavior (a tool or something), because sadly was until a runtime error was raise when I notice this, or how did we need to handle this

Comment: You can do static type checking with [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/), and/or write some actual tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a process error. An API shouldn't change its signature without considering its users. Within a project its easy, just search. Externally, the API version number should be bumped and the change should be in the change notes.

The API should have unit tests which include return value tests. "he unintentionally changed" issues should all be caught there. Since this didn't happen, a bug report against the tests should be written.

Of course, the coworker could just change those tests. But all of that should be in a code reviewed change set in your source repository. The coworker should have to justify the change and how to mitigate breakage. Since this API appears to have external clients, it should be very difficult to get an API signature change as all clients will need to be notified.